# jQuery load function after video loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a HTML code like this:

```
... <video id="abc" preload="auto" autoplay="autoplay" loop="loop" webkit-playsinline="">
    <source src="3.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video> ...
```

And I used this JS code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
"use strict";


    $("#abc").load(function () {
        console.log(3);
    });
});
```

I wanna run that function when the video loads. The JS code works with `img` tag but not with `video` tag. I want it to work like the `img` tag. Like I want it not to run when it loads videos from cache.
How can I do that?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

HTML element `video` does not have `load` event. It has others, like `loadstart`, `loadeddata` or `loadedmetadata`. See a full list of possible viedo events [here](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_av_dom.asp).

```js
$("#abc").on("loadstart", function() {
  console.log(3);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<video id="abc" preload="auto" autoplay="autoplay" loop="loop" webkit-playsinline="">
  <source src="https://www.quirksmode.org/html5/videos/big_buck_bunny.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

**loadeddata**: Fires when the browser has loaded the current frame of the audio/video
**loadedmetadata**: Fires when the browser has loaded meta data for the audio/video
**loadstart**: Fires when the browser starts looking for the audio/video

Comment: How about the cache thing? How can I run the function only when the browser doesn't use cache?

Comment: Even from cache it fires the events. I would not know a solution for an event, only triggered on first load. I'm sorry. But why is this even needed?

Comment: Does anyone know if loadstart definitely runs before "onerror"?  https://www.w3schools.com/tags/av_event_error.asp

Answer (score 3):

You must use the loadeddata event to know when the video is loaded, you can see all properties of the event here:

[loadeddata event](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/av_event_loadeddata.asp)

And an example here:

```
var video = document.getElementById("abc");
video.onloadeddata = function() {
     alert("Browser has loaded the current frame");
};
```

you can use jquery selectors too.

Comment: How does it work with cache? Does it run the function when the browser uses cache?

Comment: You can try it here: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_av_event_loadeddata . i haven't found problems with cache