# How to call $(window).on("load", function) in jQuery-3.3.1?

Tags: javascript, jquery, onload

I just now started using jquery-3.3.1, and my onload(); function not working anymore. I know this is updated, so I changed the `window.onload = function(e)` to `$(window).on("load", function (e)`, but not working... Whats the wrong with this code? How can I call the load function now?

```
$(window).on("load", function (e) {
    var videoSource = new Array();

     videoSource[0] = 'video1.mp4';
     videoSource[1] = 'video2.mp4';

var i = 1; // define i
var videoCount = videoSource.length;

function videoPlay(videoNum) {
document.getElementById("myVideo").setAttribute("src", videoSource[videoNum]);
document.getElementById("myVideo").load();
document.getElementById("myVideo").play();
}
document.getElementById('myVideo').addEventListener('ended', myHandler, false);
videoPlay(0); // play the video

function myHandler() {
    i++;
    if (i == (videoCount - 1)) {
        i = -1;
        videoPlay(0);
    } else {
        i = 0;
        videoPlay(1);
    }
}
})
```

and this is my html:

```
<video playsinline autoplay muted id="myVideo" type="video/mp4" onload="onload();" poster="poster.png"></video>
```

SOLVED: the problem originate from that, I use this `window.onload = function()` before an (or the?) `$(document).ready(function()` ... Sorry guys, I am very in javascript, just now learning the basics of this language. Now works the all your solutions, thank you very much all your replies!

Comment: Check out [this article about HTML5 Video Element with jQuery](http://www.inwebson.com/html5/custom-html5-video-controls-with-jquery/), **short, right-to-the-point, tasty**.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is my 'load' event/function not beeing executed after switching to jQuery 3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38585373/why-is-my-load-event-function-not-beeing-executed-after-switching-to-jquery-3)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you're not using jQuery except for waiting for the document to be loaded, simply replace also this with plain js

```
window.onload = function() {
    // let's go!
}
```

Note that many browsers, like safari, block autoplaying of video. Once the other browsers adopt this too your code won't work anymore.

Answer (score 2):

Use **$(document).ready()** instead of `$(window).on("load", function...`

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    console.log("ready!");
});
```

**OR** its shorthand:

```
$(function() {
    console.log("ready!");
});
```

**In your case would be:**

```
$(function() {
    var videoSource = new Array();

    videoSource[0] = 'video1.mp4';
    videoSource[1] = 'video2.mp4';

    var i = 1; // define i
    var videoCount = videoSource.length;

    function videoPlay(videoNum) {
        document.getElementById("myVideo").setAttribute("src", 
        videoSource[videoNum]);
        document.getElementById("myVideo").load();
        document.getElementById("myVideo").play();
    }

    document.getElementById('myVideo').addEventListener('ended', myHandler, false);
    videoPlay(0); // play the video

    function myHandler() {
        i++;
        if (i == (videoCount - 1)) {
            i = -1;
            videoPlay(0);
        } else {
            i = 0;
            videoPlay(1);
        }
    }
})
```

**[More on this subject.](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/)** Also checkout **[how to handle Video Element Events using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38012592/jquery-load-function-after-video-loaded)**.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `$(window).on("load")...`, use `$(document).ready(function)` instead

Also, it's worth noting that a lot of browsers are disabling autoplay now so watch out for that one.

```
$(document).ready(function (e) {
    var videoSource = new Array();

     videoSource[0] = 'video1.mp4';
     videoSource[1] = 'video2.mp4';

var i = 1; // define i
var videoCount = videoSource.length;

function videoPlay(videoNum) {
document.getElementById("myVideo").setAttribute("src", videoSource[videoNum]);
document.getElementById("myVideo").load();
document.getElementById("myVideo").play();
}
document.getElementById('myVideo').addEventListener('ended', myHandler, false);
videoPlay(0); // play the video

function myHandler() {
    i++;
    if (i == (videoCount - 1)) {
        i = -1;
        videoPlay(0);
    } else {
        i = 0;
        videoPlay(1);
    }
}
})
```